# Is there a fix amount of energy stored in magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

$B= (\mu/4× \pi) × q v (\sin\theta/r^2)$

- $ \mu = \text{ permeability of medium}$
- $q = \text{charge of the object} $
- $r = \text{distance object}$
- $v = \text{ the velocity of object}$
- $\theta$ = angle between velocity's direction and r's(distance of charge) direction

This equation needs a velocity of moving charge to tell how much magnetic field it is producing

But All velocities are relative. For example if i travel at 2 lakh km/sec from you then, you will be moving with the same velocity away from me in my view.

If the velocity changes as frame changes how can we decide the amount of energy(in magnetic fields) being released by a charge

how can we say what is the amount of magnetic field released by charge  particle?

Answer (score 1):

Amount of energy associated with EM field depends on frame of reference. Also, when the charge is moving with constant velocity, no energy is being "released". Kinetic energy of the charge is constant and magnetic energy in space around the charge is also constant. These constants depend on the frame of reference.

Comment: The charge that is releasing the magnetic field doesn't know about other charges around it so it cannot give off magnetic fields according to the charge moving around it

Comment: I don't understand your setup. Do you have two charges there?

Comment: Does more powerfulagnetic fields contain more energy? If yes then how will you calculate the actuall strength of Magnetic field since the velocity is not fixed as it changes with frames

Comment: Magnetic field has no "actual strength". Its strength at any point depends on the frame of reference. The same point can have strength 1 Tesla in one frame and 2 Tesla in other frame.

Comment: No, the setup is about only one charge releasing magnetic field. But we can take some test charges to test the magnetic field. Assume that for one Charge $q1$ the Magnetic force at $r$ is $M$ and then we test another charge $q2$ which has greater velocity relative to source charge and passes through $r$ and feels larger Magentic force. Larger force for same time period means larger energy. but how the source charge can give off different energy to different charges at same distance $r$

Comment: Why do you think source charge gives energy to test charges? It does not. Magnetic force on both test charges is perpendicular to their velocities, so no work is done by magnetic force on these test charges.

Comment: Yeah this is true that magnetic field is perpendicular but the magnetic force isn't.  Magnetic field produces that force by creating an Electric field. To get more powerful magnetic force and hence more amount energy the source charge must realease that increased amount of energy. The increase in energy can be very large if you think of velocity $q2$ - velocity$q1$ = Very very large.   But how is this possible that source charge can change the amount of energy released with $M.F.$ and sometimes the energy becomes very large.

Comment: You said,"Amount of energy associated with EM field depends on frame of reference." That's the topic of question. How can the amount of energy released by source charge change with respect to test charges. The Source charge doesn't know if anything is around it or if there is any  charge near it since there is no contact . The space is empty! Magnetic fields travel out with a fixed amount of energy independent of other charges.  But in you text you are saying totally different thing

Comment: No you are completely confused. Magnetic field of the source acts on test particles, but this action is via non-working force. Magnetic force does not work, there is no energy exchange between magnetic field energy and kinetic energy of the test particle. Energy exchanges between EM energy and kinetic energies of the particles happens only via electric force.

Comment: Okay i will remove that word "Magnetic force" but still we know that "Electric field" is created by that changing Magnetic field. But change in magnetic field can differ for different test charges moving at different velocities even without changing the motion of source charge. The Electric field made changing magnetic field is doing work. Larger the change in $M.F.$ larger the force but this doesn't seems to make any sense. How can the energy released by a source charge change for an reference

Comment: Magnetic fields seems to take energy from one place to another in space and then the Electric field prduced at that location may do work. But in the above text Magnetic fields are said to have some energy. Cause if they do not contain energy then how could that energy travel from one place to another.  Electric fields are easy to understand since the force acted is only dependent on distance ($r$) and $Q$ but in Magnetic forces(Electric field actually applies force) the force is dependent on distance($r$), $Q$ as well as motion of test charge

Comment: You seem to have various misconceptions and questions on how electromagnetism works, you better read introductory books on electromagnetism. I recommend 1) Gettys, Keller, Skove: Physics. Classical and Modern and 2) Purcell: Electricity and Magnetism.

Answer (score 1):

No. The magnetic field varies with relative velocity such that the frame-adjusted Lorentz force is the same in every frame. If you like, you can imagine that there is a single "Lorentz Field", of which the electric field and magnetic field are special cases of information normally included as vector components of the Lorentz field.

See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661883/how-is-lorentz-force-frame-independent) for further detail.

Comment: What actually happens when a Force is applied on a mass for a time period? Yes! Change in momentum and this tells us that work is being done.  In the Case of Magnetic forces work is done by Electric field is created by Magnetic field to apply force on charge $q1$ . $q1$ has got some energy but from where?   Less specific answer: From source charge $Q$. More specific answer: From Magnetic field released by $Q$ . Since there is no contact between $Q$ and $q1$ Magnetic fields is more specific answer to say. then  $M.F.$ must contain energy.  Lets discuss upto this

Comment: $g  I don't have any problem i finding a way to calculate that force but i am here for an explanation for how this electromagnetism works. We could make assumption but it must explain everything