# Deriving transformation property of $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ under Galilean transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

How can we determine the transformation property of the electric and magnetic field, $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$, under Galilean transformation **(without)** using (the $v/c\to 0$ limit of) the Lorentz transformation?

This question is inspired by the [answer by GiorgioP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/686190/164488).

Comment: Hint: $\mathbf{F}$ is invariant under in a Galilean formalism, and $\mathbf{F}=q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$. You should be able to work out the rest from there.

Comment: If you don't take the $v/c\rightarrow 0$ limit, then you will find an inconsistency somewhere if you apply a Galilean transformation to $E$ and $B$, since Maxwell's equations are not Galilean invariant.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Actually, I want to show that $m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ is invariant under Galilean transformation. To do this, we must derive the transformation property of $E,B$ by some other means. Otherwise, the argument becomes cyclic.

Comment: @Andrew Look at the answer by GiorgioP that I have linked. It shows that Newton's law $m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ is invariant under Galilean transformation. However, it derives the Galilean transformation property of $E,B$ by considering the $v/c\to 0$ limit of the Lorentz transformation property of $E,B$. I am asking whether we can find the Galilean transformation property of $E,B$ using pre-relativistic knowledge.

Comment: ${\bf E}'={\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}'=0$.

Comment: @Buzz How did you get this? Moreover, this is incorrect because it does not match with the $v/c\to 0$ limit of the Lorentz transformation. Physically, the electric field due to a point charge at rest in a frame S becomes both an electric and magnetic field in a frame S' in relative motion with S.

Comment: There are no "God-given" transformation rules. You start from a set of equations, and then you can check if any given set of transformations leaves those equations invariant or not. If you start from the $v\rightarrow 0$ limit of Maxwell's equations, you should be able to derive the Galilean transformation rules for $E$ and $B$ by looking for a linear transformation that leaves the equations invariant. But this is just a roundabout way of taking the $v\rightarrow 0$ limit of the Lorentz transformations. If you start from Maxwell's equations, the Galilean transformations just won't work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take Maxwell's equations, and look for an *approximate* symmetry that only holds to leading order in $v$, by guessing a transformation for $E$ and $B$ that is linear in $v$. This should work, but again it's just a roundabout way of taking the $v\rightarrow 0$ limit of the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: @Andrew Let me phrase it like this. In the old days of Galilean relativity, it was believed that the laws of physics i.e., Newton's law $m\vec{a}=\vec{F}$ is invariant under Galilean transformation. For an equation of the form $m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^3}(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)$, it is easy to verify that both sides of the equation are invariant under $\vec{r}'=\vec{r}-Vt$ and $t'=t$. In this process, we do not have to know Einsteinian relativity, Lorentz transformation etc.

Comment: @Andrew (Continued) Similarly, is it possible to show that both sides of $m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ are invariant without any knowledge of Einsteinian relativity? To do that one must know how E,B changes under GT without using LT or any relativistic idea. I hope I've made it clear. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah but you're not getting what I'm saying. You could also rewrite Newton's gravitational law as $m\ddot{x} = m g$, where $g$ is the gravitational field, and then your question would be how $g$ transforms. The answer is that there is another equation, Poisson's equation, that you can solve, and in the case of two point charges gives you the formula you wrote down. That whole set of equations has a Galilean symmetry. In order to answer your question, you have to tell me what equations you are assuming $E$ and $B$ satisfy. If it's Maxwell's equations, there just isn't a Galilean symmetry.

Comment: @Solidification in gravitation only involves masses (and we assume mass is conserved) and other kinematic quantities (namely position, and we know the relationship between acceleration and velocity and position), and we know how these quantities transform if measured by different observers: they measure the same mass, and kinematics gives us the rule of transformation for position and velocity, being Galilean transformations for inertial observers

Comment: @Solidification when Lorentz's force acts on a charged particle, its expression contains the electromagnetic field, and kinematics doesn't provide us with the rule of transformation for $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. What we "know", is that two inertial observers measures the same force when looking at the same system. So, the starting point for rules of transformation for EM field is (or may be, since you can start from Maxwell's equations or other principles of EM) is that two inertial observers measure the same Lorentz's force

Comment: Your question is interesting, and there is a thorough answer in the literature.  I'll try to summarize it later today.

Answer (score 3):

Accelerations are invariant under Galilean transformations, therefore forces are invariant under Galilean transformations. Full stop. If it's a force, it's invariant. It doesn't matter what the force is, so no further proof is needed. We just need to derive how the electric and magnetic fields must transform in order for this to be the case. Absent this principle as a starting point, we don't have any other grip to hold on to in a Galilean framework that won't amount to approximating the Lorentz transformation laws. Maxwell's equations are Lorentz invariant, not Galilean (they were the defining example of a system that needed Lorentz invariance to make sense). The electromagnetic Lagrangian ($\propto \mathbf{E}^2 - c^2\mathbf{B}^2$) is Lorentz invariant. $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}$ is also Lorentz invariant.

You can use the Galilean invariance of forces to derive what how the electromagnetic field must transform to maintain this invariance. Suppose the primed frame moves with respect to the unprimed frame with a velocity $\mathbf{u}$. In the unprimed frame the charge $q$ moves with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}'$ in the primed frame. Thus:
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{F} &= q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B} \\
  &= q\mathbf{E}' + q\mathbf{v}'\times\mathbf{B}'.
\end{align}

Now, $\mathbf{v}' = \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{u}$ so we get:
\begin{align}
    q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B} &= q\mathbf{E}' + q(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u})\times\mathbf{B}'\text{ and} \\
    q\mathbf{E} + q(\mathbf{v}' + \mathbf{u})\times\mathbf{B} &= q\mathbf{E}' + q\mathbf{v}'\times\mathbf{B}'
\end{align}
The definition of $\mathbf{E}$ is the force experienced by a charge at rest after gravitational and other known forces have been accounted for. So, if $\mathbf{v}=0$ or $\mathbf{v}'=0$ then we get:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{E}  &= \mathbf{E}' - \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{B}'\text{ and} \\
    \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{B} &= \mathbf{E}'.
\end{align}

Notice, these transformation laws are consistent with each-other if $\mathbf{B}$ is invariant under Galilean transformations. If you want, you can take these transformations as writ, and verify that with them the forces are invariant Galilean transformations.

But, we know that this would disagree with the first order Lorentz transformations, which would be:
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}' &= \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{B} \\
  \mathbf{B}' &= \mathbf{B} - c^{-2} \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{E}.
\end{align}
If we feed those into the primed frame Lorentz force we get:
\begin{align}
  F &= q\left(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{B}\right) + q(\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{u})\times\left(\mathbf{B} - c^{-2} \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{E}\right) \\
   &= q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B} - qc^{-2} (\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{u})\times(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{E})\\
   &= q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{uv}{c^2}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{u^2}{c^2}\right).
\end{align}
In other words, to first order in velocities over $c$, the Galilean transformation we derived agrees with the forces you'd calculate from the first order Lorentz transformation law.

If you feel it's necessary, you can derive the transformation law for $\mathbf{B}$ by imposing that the action $\int \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}^3x\, \left(\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}^2 - \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\mathbf{B}^2\right)$ has to be first order Galilean invariant, but that's equivalent to approximating the Lorentz transformation since it is the Lorentz transformations that the action is actually invariant under.

Comment: Even taking Mach's point of view, that force is *defined* by $F=ma$, it is still required to show that a possible candidate for $F$ is Galilean invariant. In this sense, Newton's second law is not enough to prove the Galilean invariance of the force. It is necessary to analyze the non-relativistic behavior of the fields, and that cannot be done without reference to the field equations. So, things are slightly more complicated. I hope to have time to add an answer later.

Comment: @GiorgioP These fields are defined by observing the forces they produce. It's only after those defining observations that we deduce other field properties, like their field equations. Since observed forces are Galilean invariant, you can derive the transformation laws the fields must obey from this fact. What you describe sounds like a "guess & check" approach, sorry "postulate & derive." Point I'm making: that approach is not "necessary". It's a useful mathematical exercise, but nothing more.

Comment: Your point of view is fully consistent with a Machian point of view. But that is not the only possibility offered by Physics. Even sticking to Mach's point of view, in order to say something about how forces depend on their variables, one should ideally perform as many measurements of force as many different values exist for the corresponding variables. But in a real situation, one starts from a guess about the functional dependence of the forces on their variables, and he/she has to verify whether it is consistent with the invariance of the force.

Answer (score 2):

Look for $v/c \sim 0$ of the transformations, as an example non-relativistic approximation in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity.

You can start with the assumption that Lorentz's force is invariant, defining
$\mathbf{e}^* \approx \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{b}$.

Then you can use continuity equation for the electric charge assuming $\rho^* \approx \rho$ to get $\mathbf{j}^* \approx \mathbf{j} - \rho \mathbf{v}$

And then put these expressions in Maxwell's equation, do some algebra to get at the "first order" $\mathbf{b}^* \approx \mathbf{b} - \dfrac{\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{e}}{c^2}$, where $\mathbf{v}/c^2$ appears.

Playing around with equations, you get a finer approximation (the "first order" approximation) of the current density $\rho^* \approx \rho - \dfrac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{j}}{c^2}$.

These are not exact transformations, since Electromagnetism is not compatible with Galilean transformations.

**Integral balance equations.** If you feel comfortable with integral equations of electromagnetism, and time derivative of physical quantities on moving volumes, surfaces and lines, I leave a reference for some notes that illustrates the definition the approximate transformations:
https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/EM/em_integral.html

If you don't feel comfortable with the time derivation on moving domains, check this:
https://basics.altervista.org/test/Math/time_derivatives_of_integrals/time_derivatives_of_integrals.html

Comment: If we want to check whether the Lorentz force expression is invariant under Galilean transformation (GT), we cannot start by assuming it to be invariant. We must fist find the transformation property of E,B under GT anf then check whether it is invariant. The point is that I want to verify the invariance of $m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ without using relativistic ideas/equations.

Comment: The point is that the force you measure is invariant, thus Lorentz's force is invariant. Imagine two observers moving with relative velocity $v$. These are inertial observers in the limit of classical mechanics, and they measure the same force (remember that Physics is mainly about measurements and things you can measure).

Comment: Here the apparent contradiction, and the first law of transformation of $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. If one of the observers moves with the same velocity as the particle, he measures $\mathbf{v}^*$, and thus $\mathbf{F} = q (\mathbf{e} + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{b}) = q ( \mathbf{e}^* + \mathbf{0} \times \mathbf{b}^*) = \mathbf{F}^*$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a step back and start with a more basic question: "what does it mean to *ask* how a field transforms?"

This is the answer I would give to that question:

Say we set up some experimental conditions, and measure a value of the field at some location. Then, we change the experimental conditions in some way. The *transformation* of the field is the difference between the new value of the field, and the old value of the field.

Now, what do we need to know to calculate the transformation? *In general*, we would have to *re-solve the problem from scratch* with the new conditions. For example, if the original experiment involved one point charge, and the new problem involved two, to calculate the transformation we would need to solve for the field given two point charges, and compare it to the solution we got with one point charge.

*However*, if the change of experimental conditions is a *symmetry*, then calculating the transformation is *much simpler*. If we start with some charge distribution, then rotate that charge distribution, we *don't* need to re-solve the equations, to calculate the field in the new conditions, and therefore to compute the transformation. Knowing the value of the field in the original set up, plus knowing the axis and angle of the rotation, is enough information to completely determine the new field.

When we ask how a field transforms, we usually have this latter situation in mind implicitly. We are supposing that the system has some symmetry, and asking how the fields change under that symmetry.

Now let's think about electromagnetism. How do we calculate the fields given some experimental conditions? We solve Maxwell's equations. So how do we determine the transformation of a field under boosts? Well, the hard way would be to solve Maxwell's equations for some charge configuration in one reference frame. Then, consider the same situation, but with that charge configuration moving at some velocity. Then, re-solve Maxwell's equations for the fields in the new frame. Then, we compare the solutions.

But, because (Lorentz) boosts are a symmetry of Maxwell's equations, there is a faster method, which is to prove that a certain transformation of the fields leaves the equations invariant. This guarantees that this transformation will relate solutions in different frames. To *derive* the form of the transformation, a way to proceed is to *guess* that $E$ and $B$ transform linearly under a boost (you could think of this as a simple starting point, that happens to work), and solve for the parameters of the linear transformation that leave Maxwell's equations invariant. Once we have derived the form of the transformations, the proof is fairly simple. Once we have proven the symmetry at the level of the equations, then we don't need to bother re-solving for the fields in the new frame. That is the point of a symmetry, and it is the reason it's meaningful to ask how the fields transform in the first place. All you need to know to calculate what the fields will do in the new frame, are the values of the fields in the original frame, plus the boost magnitude and direction. The solution to this is precisely the usual form of the Lorentz transformations of the $E$ and $B$ fields.

Now, if you try to shift $x$ and $t$ by a *Galilean* transformation, you will find that Maxwell's equations *are not invariant* for any choice of transformation for $E$ and $B$. If you make this change to the coordinates, you really will need to re-solve the equations for $E$ and $B$; you are looking at a different scenario where the physics has actually changed, you cannot simply rely on the symmetry to relate the solution in the new frame to the solution in the old frame. Therefore, it is not really even meaningful to ask how $E$ and $B$ transform under a Galilean transformation. If you try to answer this question mathematically by solving the for the fields with the transformed coordinates after a Galilean transformation, you'll find that the new solution is not determined in a simple way in terms of the old one. Physically, that just means that it doesn't really make sense to ask how $E$ and $B$ transform under a Galilean transformation. **The fact that the Galilean transformation has a name, does not imply that it is physically meaningful to assign transformation rules to $E$ and $B$ under a Galilean transformation.**

Now of course, Galilean transformations are a limit of Lorentz transformations, so they are not completely irrelevant. Indeed, Galilean transformations are an *approximate* symmetry of Maxwell's equations, that hold to linear order in $v/c$. Working out the details of this is the content of Sean E. Lake's and basics's very nice answers. But again, keep in mind the logic: we start from the equations, and see what symmetries the equations have. We are only really interested in looking at transformation rules for symmetries of the equations, because only under a symmetry it is meaningful to ask how the field transforms without having to re-solve the equations from scratch.